# Poll an Express server with $.get regularly

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

There is an Express server with a server time generator. The generated time are sent to the client page `gtm.hbs`. How do I poll the server regularly from the client page? I’m looking for an ajax solution.

Here’s the server side code stored in `\routes\getTime.js`:

```
module.exports = {  
    sendCurrentUTCTimeString: function(req, res, next) {
        var currentUTCTime = new Date();
        var currentUTCHours = currentUTCTime.getUTCHours();
        var currentUTCMinutes = currentUTCTime.getUTCMinutes();
        var currentUTCSeconds = currentUTCTime.getUTCSeconds();

        currentUTCHours = ( currentUTCHours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentUTCHours;
        currentUTCMinutes = ( currentUTCMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentUTCMinutes;
        currentUTCSeconds = ( currentUTCSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentUTCSeconds;
        currentUTCHours = ( currentUTCHours == 24 ) ? "00" : currentUTCHours;

        function pad(number, length) {
            var str = "" + number;
            while (str.length < length) {
                str = '0' + str;
            }
            return str;
        }

        var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        offset = ((offset < 0 ? '+' : '-') + pad(parseInt(Math.abs(offset / 60)), 2) + pad(Math.abs(offset % 60), 2));
        offset = offset.match(/[\+-][0-9][0-9]/)[0];
        res.send({currentUTCTime: currentUTCTime, currentUTCHours: currentUTCHours, currentUTCMinutes: currentUTCMinutes, currentUTCSeconds:currentUTCSeconds, offset: offset});
    }
}
```

The `gettime.hbs` page code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            var currentUTCHours;
            var currentUTCMinutes;
            var currentUTCSeconds;
            var offset;
            $.get('/gettime', function(data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
                currentUTCHours = data.currentUTCHours;
                currentUTCMinutes = data.currentUTCSeconds;
                currentUTCSeconds = data.currentUTCMinutes;
                offset = data.offset;
                $('#currentUTCHours').text(currentUTCHours);
                $('#currentUTCMinutes').text(currentUTCMinutes);
                $('#currentUTCSeconds').text(currentUTCSeconds);
                $('#offset').text(offset);
            });

            console.log('currentUTCHours: ' + currentUTCHours);
        }, 1500);
    });
</script>

currentUTCHours: <span id="currentUTCHours"></span><br>
currentUTCMinutes: <span id="currentUTCMinutes"></span><br>
currentUTCSeconds: <span id="currentUTCSeconds"></span><br>
offset: <span id="offset"></span><br>
```

Here I wanted to render a page that would poll the server then fill the four `<span>`s with the server response values.

The route to connect the server and the client is

```
app.get('/gettime', getTime.sendCurrentUTCTimeString);
app.get('/gtm', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('gettime', {});
});
```

Comment: Every server sends a `Date` header with every response. I recommend you use that header value instead of the rolling your own mechanism.

Comment: Regularly polling the server in an Express app seems an odd way to do it when you could use Socket.io quite easily to push the changes to the client.

Comment: Agreed. Nevertheless this was the way I needed to solve this. I did will post the solution tomorrow.

Comment: Posted the solution above in case it'll be of use to others.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#currentUTCHours').text(currentUTCHours);
$('#currentUTCSeconds').text(currentUTCSeconds);
```

Should be inside $.get() to make changes visible.